# It is mandatory to set a layout in a webview android app?

Tags: android, layout, webview

I'am a newby developing android apps
I have done all my app in HTML5, PHP, SQL, etc, so I want to make an android app with a webview component linking to my site.
Should I add a root Layout to my app or just webview would be fine?

Answer (score 0):

```
WebView webView =new WeView(this);
..
..//Config webview properties
..
setContentView(webView);
```

Doing this in your onCreate of your Activity should be fine